# Drag and Drop from WPF application to excel

Tags: wpf, excel

I have WPF application consists of some Text Box and List View. I want to implement Drag and Drop feature from my Application to MS Excel Cell. I want to Drag some text data from WPF application into Excel Cell.

I know how to implement the Drag events from Source. But I don't know how to implement DragEnter, DragOver, DragLeave or Drop events into Excel.

Please help me out with this.

Thanks